# How to solve assertion error in Google Colab?

Tags: file-upload, google-colaboratory

I'm attempting to write some code to generate a model for 3D segmentation. I'm using a model code provided by the creators of Stardist to write my code but I keep getting an assertion error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here is the code provided:

[Screenshot of the code from Stardist github page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApZHw.png)

Here is my attempt at reconstructing the code with the error I get when I attempt to run it.

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqM7t.png)

I was wondering if people had any solutions for the problem I'm getting? I'm almost completely new to coding and using github as a whole so not sure if there's a way to create a direct download link, like they have, or if it should just be able to find my files directly off my hardrive. I also attach a picture of how my files are labelled so can't see why the code can't assertain they have the same labeling:

[Image of my pathway for first, the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG9HE.png)

and secondly, [the masks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTwvi.png).

Thank you all,

N

Comment: can you share the clickable link of stardist GitHub repo? Because i try the link from the image but it shows a 404 error.